# Windows 8.1 Selection Box

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, selection, mouse-cursor

OS: Windows 8.1
Okay, you know how when you click and drag your cursor across the desktop and a blue bordered box appears? Well my problem... I guess isn't that big, but I'd like to fix it. My computer no longer has the blue bordered box, it has changed into a colorless dashed bordered box, like the ones in the older Windows OS. This happened after I restarted my computer after using IObit's Advanced SystemCare Ultimate 7 to clean my computer for the first time. I suspect it has done something to the registry, since it has a registry defragging/fixing tool. So does anybody know how to bring back the blue bordered selection box back? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the "System Properties" control panel (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> → `sysdm.cpl`). In the "Advanced" tab, under "Performance", click "Settings" and make sure "Show translucent selection rectangle" is enabled.